# How to convert the python Tkinter listbox into Tcl/Tk?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

How to convert the following listbox python code in to Tcl/Tk?

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Dude0")
root.geometry("400x400")

my_listbox = Listbox(root)
my_listbox.pack(pady=15)

root.mainloop()
```

Seems like all the examples for tk are for python these days instead of TCL.

Comment: The site https://tkdocs.com has a useful tutorial that shows python and tcl code snippets so you can see the differences.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the translation:

```
package require Tk

wm title . "Dude0"
wm geometry . "400x400"

listbox .my_listbox
pack .my_listbox -pady 15
```

With `wish` you automatically get a root window named ".", and wish will automatically listen for events so you don't need to call the equivalent of `mainloop`. For other widgets such as your listbox, you need to give them a path that uses "." as separators. So `.my_listbox` represents a child of the root window. You can assign that to a variable, but in my experience it's good enough to just give the widgets themselves user-friendly names.

Most other things that are methods in tkinter will be procs in tcl, and kwargs in tkinter are option/value pairs in tcl (options begin with a dash). So instead of `my_listbox.pack(padx=15)`, in tcl you would do `pack .my_listbox -padx 15`.

[tkdocs.com](https://tkdocs.com/) has an excellent [tutorial](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html) that lets you see examples written in python, tcl, ruby, and perl.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my transcription of your python code will help you, but I'm agree with @GlennJackman, tkdocs will be more interesting than my response... that said, the code written in Tcl :

```
package require Tk ; # from tkinter import *

set root .root 
toplevel $root ; # root = Tk()

wm title $root "Dude0" ; # root.title("Dude0")
wm geometry $root "400x400" ; # root.geometry("400x400")

listbox $root.lb ; # my_listbox = Listbox(root)

pack $root.lb -pady 15 ; # my_listbox.pack(pady=15)
```

Comment: This ends up creating two windows, not one.